# No se puede resolver el símbolo BufferedImage

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para descargar fotos en secuencia. El código es este:

```
package org.matematicasfacil.myapplication;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class PhotosInSequence {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Do you want to download all photos? (y/n): ");
    //Definir nuevo escáner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Lee una cadena del usuario y obtén el primer personaje en minúscula
    char choice = sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    while(true) {
        if(choice == 'y') {
            getAllPhotos();
            break;
        }

        else {
            System.out.print("Please enter a valid choice (y/n): ");
            choice = sc.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}

//Método para descargar todas las fotos disponibles
public static void getAllPhotos() {
    long idNumber;
    for(idNumber = 150030001; idNumber < 150031146; idNumber ++) {
        getPhoto(idNumber);
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
}

//Método para generar URL a partir del número de ID
private static URL getUrl(long idNumber) throws MalformedURLException{
    //Hacer urlString desde el número de ID con el cual generar URL
    String urlString = "http://exams.kluniversity.in/photos/" + idNumber + ".jpg";

    //Inicializar un objeto URL vacío
    URL url = null;

    //Obtener el objeto URL de urlString
    url = new URL(urlString);
    return url;
}

//Método para obtener el nombre del archivo de salida desde el número de ID
private static File getOutputFileName(long idNumber) {
    //Realice una cadena de archivo de salida desde el número de ID con el que se generará un nuevo archivo de imagen
    String outputFileString = idNumber + ".jpg";

    //Obtenga un nuevo objeto de archivo de la cadena de archivo de salida.
    File outputFile = new File(outputFileString);
    return outputFile;
}

//Método para obtener la foto
private static void getPhoto(long idNumber) {
    try {
        //Leer la imagen de URL a una imagen almacenada en el búfer
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getUrl(idNumber));

        //Escriba la imagen en el archivo de salida pasando la imagen almacenada, tipo de archivo, nombre del archivo de salida
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", getOutputFileName(idNumber));

    } catch(MalformedURLException muex) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL.");
    } catch(IOException ioex) {
        System.out.println("\nError for " + idNumber + ". Photo doesn't exist\n");
        //ioex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Pero recibo el siguiente mensaje:

> cannot resolve symbol BufferedImage
>   cannot resolve symbol ImageIO

Por lo cual no funciona el siguiente código:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getUrl(idNumber));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", getOutputFileName(idNumber));
```

¿Cómo resuelvo el BufferedImage e ImageIO? ¿O cómo cambio el último código?

Comment: Usando el código que compartes, no he podido reproducir el problema. No veo ningún mensaje de error.

Comment: ¿Te da el error al compilar o al ejecutar? ¿En qué plataforma trabajas? ¿Más en concreto: es algún Unix/Linux sin GUI?

Comment: Qué versión de Java usas?

Comment: Al compilar sale:  

"error: package java.awt.image does not exist"  
"error: package javax.imageio does not exist"  
"error: cannot find symbol class BurfferedImage"  
"error: cannot find symbol variable ImageIO"  

Trabajo en windows 8.1 de 64bit y utilizo Java 9.0.4  

Otro dato estoy utilizando Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: Esos paquetes no están disponibles para Android, por eso no se encuentran dichas clases.

Comment: Gracias E. Betanzos. ¿Sabes como lo haría en Android?. Ayuda por favor